# How to convert case class into string

Tags: scala

If I have a case class like below:

```
case class Student(name: String, activities: Seq[String], grade: String)
```

And I have a List like this:

```
val students = List(
      Student("John",List("soccer","Video Games"),"9th"),
      Student("Jane",List("sword fighting","debate"),"10th")
     )
```

How can I convert the entire thing into a string like below:

```
johnsoccervideogames9thjaneswordfightingdebate10th
```

I'd like to take an MD5 has of this string.

Comment: Override `toString` method of the case class

Comment: @texasbruce overriding `toString` on a case class just for a one time use seems like a really bad idea...

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez He's not quite clear about his requirement. Don't think he mentioned this is a one time use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you are expecting.

```
students.map( student => student.name + student.activities.mkString + student.grade).mkString.toLowerCase.replaceAll("\\s", "")
```

Comment: When concatenating large Strings, always use **String Interpolator**: `student => s"${student.name}${student.activities.mkString}${student.grade}"`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is this possible to do in a sorting as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367311/how-to-sort-contents-of-case-class