# How to sort contents of case class

Tags: scala, sorting

If I have a case class like below:

```
case class Student(name: String, activities: Seq[String], grade: String)
```

And I have a List like this:

```
val students = List(
  Student("John", List("soccer", "Video Games"), "9th"),
  Student("Jane", List("sword fighting", "debate"), "10th"),
  Student("Boy Wonder", List("1", "5", "2"), "5th")
)
```

How can I sort the contents based on `name` and `activities` attributes to form a string? In the scenario above the string would be:

```
boywonder_1_2_5_5th_jane_debate_swordfighting_10th_john_soccer_videogames_9th
```

The sorting in this case is done like this:

- First the elements are sorted with `name` -- Thats why in the final string `boywonder` comes first
- Then that elements' `activities` are sorted as well -- Thats why `Boy Wonder's` activities are sorted as `1_2_5`

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly do you want to sort things?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've updated the question explaining the sorting as well as added `_` in the final output string so it is clear what the output is and how it is sorted based on the attributes of the case class

Comment: Your underscore `_` placement is inconsistent. The `activities` are underscore separated for "John" and "Jane" but not for "Boy Wonder".

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Make everything lowercase.
2. Sort the inner list `activities`.
3. Sort the outer list `students`, by `name`.
4. Turn everything into a **String**.

Here is the code.

```
students
  .map { student =>
    student.copy(
      name = student.name.toLowerCase,
      activities = student.activities.sorted.map(activity => activity.toLowerCase)
    )
  }.sortBy(student => student.name)
  .map(student => s"${student.name}${student.activities.mkString}${student.grade}")
  .mkString
  .replaceAll("\\s", "")

 // res: String = "boywonder1255thjanedebateswordfighting10thjohnvideogamessoccer9th"
```